# SGEN: The top XML element from namespace references distinct types

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following classes (all defined in the same namespace, Test.NamespaceTest):

```
[XmlRootAttribute("rootTag")]
public class BaseClass
{
}


[XmlRootAttribute("rootTag")]
public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

and similarly

```
[XmlRootAttribute("rootTag")]
public class Class1
{
}


[XmlRootAttribute("rootTag")]
public class Class2
{
}
```

When sgen tries to create the serialization assemblies for these classes, I get the following error (same thing for BaseClass and MyClass):

```
The top XML element 'rootTag' from namespace " references distinct types Test.NamespaceTest.Class1 and Test.NamespaceTest.Class2. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.
```

Now, these classes should use the same root name so I defined the XmlRootAttribute.  What do I need to do in order to get sgen to work?  These classes are serialized and sent to existing services as SOAP requests so if I add namespace values, couldn't that mess up the service when it tries to deserialize the request, since no namespaces are originally defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after adding some namespace attributes.